# Test Results Analyzer Plugin for GitLab

Tags: unit-testing, jenkins, gitlab

Jenkins has nice plugin for test results.
Test Results Analyzer Plugin ([plugin url](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Test+Results+Analyzer+Plugin)).

How to attach the same dashboard (with test results) for GitLab?

Comment: Hi Igor, do you have any experience about it now? There is a project but not supported anymore "Junitth" http://junitth.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

Here is my googling result:

Gitlab has "pages" feature but it depends on artifact life and only the last one is shown.
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/junit_test_reports.html

On the other hand there is an open and long story issue about this requirement for gitlab besides lots of closed ones.
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/34102

Here the gitlab's info in this comparison page:
https://about.gitlab.com/comparison/gitlab-vs-jenkins.html

"Many languages use frameworks that automatically run tests on your code and create a report: one example is the JUnit format that is common to different tools. GitLab supports browsing artifacts and you can download reports, but we’re still working on a proper way to integrate them directly into the product."

I found a project for a complete solution and fully supported. I just started with this one and for now it is unbelievable. Just upload your reports to it. There are a lot of plug in support.
http://reportportal.io/